# Regex replace to create templating in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
{{imagename.jpg|left|The caption for this image. Includes a variety of chars}}
<p>Some text, lots of paragraphs here.</p>
{{anotherimage.jpg|right|Another caption.}}
```

What I'm trying to do is to parse out the `{{}}` bits then pass them through a function. What I have so far is:

```
function template_function($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
}

function parse_images($string) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('!\{\{([^}])\}\}!', 'template_function', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Can someone give me a hand with the regex so that I end up with the matches being run through `print_r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function template_function($matches) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}

function parse_images($string) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{([^}]*)\}\}/', 'template_function', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Have also modified `print_r($matches[1]);` so that the the actual match is printed.

Comment: So, I missed the bleeding *! I knew that I must be almost there! This is why Stack Overflow is so awesome - just getting someone else to glance at your code is very very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `*` (or, perhaps the `+`) quantifier.  Your original expression would only match a single, non-`}` character.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('!\{\{([^}]*)\}\}!', 'template_function', $string);
```